# JQuery Steps vertical tab alignment with body

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a wizard with JQuery Steps and I'm having problems with the form area lining up beside the vertical tabs.  I've created a simplified example to demonstrate what I'm getting.

Here's what I'm getting.  The body should be right of the labels...not below it...

[image]

I've created a Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Steps Test</title>
<link type="text/css" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link type="text/css" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/steps/steps.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/steps/jquery.steps.js">    </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var form = $("#application-form");

form.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
    $('#message').hide(0);

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;        }
});


});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="application-form" class='form2' >


<h3>Your personal information</h3>
<section>
</section>

<h3>School Info</h3>
<section>
</section>

<h3>Professional Licensure</h3>
<section>
</section>

<h3>Expected Professional Employment</h3>
<section>
</section>
<h3>Important Questons</h3>
<section>
</section>
</form>

</body>
```

``

Comment: If I were you, I would try another way. I would separate my view in two divs. One with `float: left`, and another with `float: right`. I would put my `headers` on left and the `sections` on right.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this.  In steps.css, I overroad the clear:both in this section with clear:right in the vertical section.

```
.wizard > .content
{
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em;
    min-height: 100px; // 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    clear:both; /* <-- */
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

}

.wizard.vertical > .content
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
    width: 65%;
    clear:right; /* <--- */
}
```